# USB Cannot be mounted only as ready only

Tags: usb, permissions, filesystem, root, read-only

I have an usb in read only mode:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
file: media/user/USB/
owner: user
group: user user::rwx group::r-x other::r-x
```

Running `fsck -p /dev/sdc1`, I receive:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2 /dev/sdc1 is mounted.

WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you
***WILL*** cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.


Do you really want to continue<n>? yes fsck.ext2: Permission denied
while trying to open /dev/sdc1 You must have r/w access to the
filesystem or be root
```

`sudo fsck -p /dev/sdc1` or `sudo dosfsck /dev/sdc1`:

```
*** Filesystem was changed *** The changes have not yet been written, you can still choose to leave the filesystem unmodified: 1) Write
changes 2) Leave filesystem unchanged [12?q]? 1 /dev/sdc1: 5 files,
71844/3754495 clusters *Writing 512 bytes at 3072 failed: Operation not
permitted Writing 512 bytes at 0 failed: Operation not permitted
Writing 4 bytes at 1000 failed: Operation not permitted*
```

`sudo fdisk /dev/sdc1`:

```
fdisk: failed to write disklabel: Operation not permitted
```

`sudo rm filename.mkv`:

```
rm: cannot remove 'filename.mkv': Read-only file
system
```

`sudo chown user:user /media/user/USB/`:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/media/user/USB/': Read-only file system
```

Mounted/unmounted does not matter I cannot change or modify the USB tried with `sudo -i`, `sudo su` does not helped. I have checked all the guides online but one of the above command helped the person resolved the issue but not for me. The USB has no visible read only mode and this never occured before.

I also tried to removed its entry from `sudo nano /etc/fstab` but it did not helped.

Comment: Many thanks, it is way more easy to read than before!

Comment: You should boot *live* media first, then perform the `fsck` on your USB-media (ie. boot a different OS in *live* media to perform the checks on your USB media).  A pasted message shows you attempting to `fsck` a mounted partition

Comment: Yes but it is actually not a boot media, it was formatted by an LG tv and contains only the TV's files and one .mkv which was copied partially.